# Shell Script syntax error: unexpected end of file (Tried Several Ans')

Tags: linux, shell, asterisk

I am very new to Linux/Asterisk. I am trying to write a script but, when I execute it, I see the error shown below.

The script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
asteriskbin=`which asterisk`
interval=10
trunk=”<test>”
run=true
while [[ "$run" == "true" ]]; do
    checktrunk=`$asteriskbin -rx “sip show peer $trunk” | grep Status | grep -wc OK`
    if [[ $checktrunk == 0 ]]; then
        echo “<TEST Trunk Down>” 
    else
        echo “SIP trunk registration OK.”
    fi
    sleep $interval
    exit 1
```

Debug error is as following:

```
bash -x trunks.sh
++ which asterisk 
+ asteriskbin=/usr/sbin/asterisk
+ interval=10
+ trunk=$'\342\200\235test\342\200\235'
+ run=true
trunks.sh: line 15: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

This might be a duplicate post but, from my search, the given answers such as `chmod 755 script.sh`, `exit 0`, `exit 1`, or `dos2unix script.sh` did not work.

Comment: Where is the end of your `while` loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aren't you missing a `done` to terminate the `while` block? I assume a line before `exit 1`.

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick! Added done before exit 1 but now I see followin... would appreciate if you could help. 

trunks.sh: line 9: TEST: No such file or directory 

I do have a trunk named test and I can also see it if I do sip show peer test

Comment: @user3761509 Consider marking this answer as accepted (since it answers the question you asked), and post any new questions separately.

Comment: @thatotherguy agree about accepting, but the follow up is really tiny: @user3761509 you need to escape special characters like `<` and `>`, please read up on escaping special chars in bash (hint: `\<`)

Comment: Okay thanks a lot. This has answered my question. But I am unable to mark it, as it says Vote Up requires 15 reputation. :(

Comment: @user3761509 No worries :)

Comment: Done :D Thanks @snowdragon  

Thanks thatotherguy